# Efficient way for finding Shortest Palindrome from Arraylist of strings

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I am trying to solve this problem in java. I have an **arraylist of palindromic** strings. I have to find the shortest palindrome string out of the given array list. I have solved the question but was looking at getting feedback on my code and also how I can try to make the code more efficient/better.

Here is the code what I have tried.

In this case, size would be 3, since that is the length of the **smallest palindromic string**.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class ShortestPalindrome {
    public static int isShortestPalindrome(ArrayList<String> list) {
        int smallest = list.get(0).length();
        boolean ret = false;
        for (String element : list) {
            ret = isPalindrome(element);
            if (ret) {
                if (element.length() < smallest) 
                    smallest = element.length();                
            }
        }
        return smallest;
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
        String str = "";
        boolean result = false;

        if (input.length() == 1 || input.length() == 0)
            return true;

        if (input.charAt(0) != input.charAt(input.length() - 1))
            return false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.toLowerCase());
        str = sb.reverse().toString();
        if (input.equals(str)) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        array.add("malayam");
        array.add("aba");
        array.add("abcdeyugugi");
        array.add("nitin");
        int size = isShortestPalindrome(array);
        System.out.println("Shortest length of string in list:" + size);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you sort the strings in the list by length and start with the shortest, you can stop once you found a palindrom. Whether this is more efficient I don't know. But for expensive tests, I'd go for this way as sorting by length should be cheap.

Comment: Reversing a string, then comparing it to another one, is a wasteful way to determine whether it's a palindrome or not. Obviously for short strings it won't be as bad as for long ones

Comment: newbie, you asked a question and you didn't bother to stay in this site just to check is there an answer or answers to your question. I think it isn't good practice... ;)

Comment: Hey sorry. i am new here. Till yesterday, there was only 1 comment which i had read. Will check the other comments today. Am i supposed to upvote them. I did do it for one of the comments i saw yesterday. Sorry but it wasn't intentional.

Comment: @newbie You can upvote any answer you like. Also you can select an answer as accepted if your question is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of comments regarding your code:

1. In general - if you break your problem to smaller parts, there are efficient solutions all around.
2. As **@AKSW** mentioned in his comment, if - in any case - we have to check each string's length, it's better to do it in the beginning - so we don't run the relatively expensive method `isPalindrome()` with irrelevant strings.
   (Just notice I override the given list with the sorted one, even though initializing a new sorted list is trivial)
3. The main improvement that I made is in the `isPalindrome()` method:

   - Reversing a string of length `n` takes *n* time and additional *n* space. Comparing the two takes also *n* time.
     **Overall: 2n time, n space**
   - Comparing each two matching characters (from the beginning and from the end) takes *2* additional space (for the integers) and approximately *n/2* time.
     **Overall: n/2 time, 2 space**

Obviously when using limits for complexity calculations, the time complexities are both the same - *O(n)* - but the second solution is still 4 times cheaper and cost a negligible amount of space.

Therefore I believe this is the most efficient way to achieve your test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class ShortestPalindrome {
    public static int isShortestPalindrome(ArrayList<String> list) {
        // Sorts the given ArrayList by length
        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
        for (String element : list) {
            if(isPalindrome(element)) {
                return element.length();
            }
        }
        return -1; // If there is no palindrome in the given array
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
        String lowerCased = input.toLowerCase();
        int pre = 0;
        int end = lowerCased.length() - 1;
        while (end > pre) {
            if (lowerCased.charAt(pre) != lowerCased.charAt(end))
                return false;
            pre ++;
            end --;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("malayam", "aba", "abcdeyugugi", "nitin"));
        int size = isShortestPalindrome(array);
        System.out.println("Shortest length of string in list: " + size);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I've tested this algorithm with the following list. Sorting the list before checking for palindromes reduces run time in 50%.

> "malayam", "aba", "abcdeyugugi", "nitin", "sadjsaudifjksdfjds", "sadjsaudifjksdfjdssadjsaudifjksdfjds", "sadjsaudifjksdfjdssadjsaudifjksdfjdssadjsaudifjksdfjds", "a"

Comment: Your `isPalindrome` is almost the same as @yassin method. The only difference is that you're making **new** `String` (`toLowerCase`). We should do some benchmark to see what way is quicker. Also, sorting the `List` doesn't necessary improve the speed of all process (depending on many factors).

Comment: @zlakad I believe SO archive stays here for the next generations, therefore I've added my explanation to the question, regardless of other answers. **To the point:** sorting the list necessarily improves run-time, in any case that the shortest palindrome isn't the first element

Comment: I didn't criticize you at all... I assume that we need to read **all** the answers before we post our answer - maybe it is already answered in our way. About sorting - you might be right (right now I don't have a time to consider all the arguments) ... Good luck, friend

Comment: Also, according to your example of sorting the list of stings based on the length, there are just **two** replacements. Nevertheless, I will up vote your answer right now.

Comment: And, in my answer anyone can add `.sorted()` right after the `list.parallelStream`. So, I think your answer is really useful.

Comment: @GalAbra sorting doesn't necessarily improve runtime! E.g. if every string is very short (size <= 3) 3N is surely smaller than NlogN for large N

Comment: Also your implementation doesn't use constant space, as the string is copied in the beginning, as @zlakad also noted. This also should not be ignored when calculating the time complexity, String.toLowerCase is O(N)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest improvement to your code is to only check whether a string is a palindrome, if it's length is smaller than `smallest`.

Btw the initialization `int smallest = list.get(0).length();` is not correct, imagine the first element not being a palindrome and being of smallest size of all strings. You should do `int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Also the check

```
if (input.charAt(0) != input.charAt(input.length() - 1))
            return false;
```

is incorrect, as you don't convert the characters to lower case (as you do later), thus `"ajA"` would not be a palindrome.

There are further improvements of your code possible:

You could replace the palindrome checking by copying and reversing with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length() / 2; ++i)
    if (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) != Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i)))
        return false;
```

Here there is no copy necessary and in the average case it might be faster (as it can terminate early).

Also, like AKSW mentioned, it might be faster to sort the strings by length and then you can terminate early, once you found a palindrome.

Comment: So, in your case "ajA" isn't palindrome?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. Didn't realize about the first point.

Answer (score 0):

Below simple code should work for you. 
**First check for length and then check is it actually palindrome or not.
If yes, then just store it in smallest**

```
public static int isShortestPalindrome(ArrayList<String> list) {
    Integer smallest = null;
    for(String s:list){
        if ( (smallest == null || s.length()< smallest) && new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s) ){
                smallest = s.length();
        }
    }
    return smallest == null ? 0 :smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stream version:

```
OptionalInt minimalLenOfPalindrome
            = list.paralellStream()
                    .filter(st -> {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(st);
                        String reversedSt = sb.reverse().toString();
                        return st.equalsIgnoreCase(reversedSt);
                    })
                    .mapToInt(String::length)
                    .min();
```

Thanks for @yassin answer I am changing above code with:

```
public class SOFlow {

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() / 2; ++i) {
            if (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) != Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i))) {
            return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("cAcc");
        list.add("a;;;;a");
        list.add("aJA");
        list.add("vrrtrrr");
        list.add("cAccccccccc");

        OptionalInt minimalLenOfPalindrome
                = list.parallelStream()
                        .filter(SOFlow::isPalindrome)
                        .mapToInt(String::length)
                        .min();

        System.out.println(minimalLenOfPalindrome);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 streams, and considering sorting first, for the same reasons as others:

```
boolean isPalindrome (String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.toLowerCase());
    return sb == sb.reverse();
}

public static int isShortestPalindrome(ArrayList<String> list) {
    return (list.stream().sorted ((s1, s2) -> { 
        return s1.length () - s2.length (); 
    })
    .filter (s-> isPalindrome (s))
    .findFirst ()
    .map (s -> s.length ())
    .orElse (-1));
}
```

If you have many Strings of equal, minimal length, of very big length, only non palindromic in the very middle, you might spend much time in isPalindrome and prefer something like isPalindrome1 over isPalindrome.

If we assume a Million Strings of equally distributed length from 1000 to 2000 characters, we would end up with concentration on in avg. 1000 Strings. If most of them are equal except on few characters, close to the middle, then fine tuning that comparison might be relevant. But finding a palindrome early terminates our search, so the percentage of palindromes is of heavy influence on the performance too.

```
private static boolean isPalindrome1 (String s) {
    String input = s.toLowerCase (); 
    int len = input.length ();
    for (int i = 0, j = len -1; i < len/2 && j > len/2; ++i, --j)
        if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt (j))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

The Result of the stream sorting and filtering is an Option, which is great opportunity to signal, that nothing was found. I sticked to your interface of returning int and return -1 if nothing is found, which has to be properly evaluated, of course, by the caller.